# C# IEEE754 Rounding

Tags: c#, double, precision, ieee-754

Consider the following C# code...

```
double x = Math.Round(72.6d, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
double y = Math.Round(82.6d, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
```

`x` becomes `72.59` and `y` becomes `82.6`.

But why? Going by this [IEEE754 convertor](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), the fractional part for both is identical. So why don't they give the same result?.

I can fix the issue by doing the following `(double)Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(72.6d), 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero)`. But I'm more interested in knowing the answer to why it doesn't appear to work as expected.

Comment: You get that if you use `MidpointRounding.ToEven` .

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I want to keep 2 dp and truncate the rest without rounding. Which is what `ToZero` is supposed to be for I thought. e.g. if I had `9.858` I want `9.85`. If I use `ToEven` this would give `9.86` which is not what I want.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser

Comment: Per the documentation, `MidpointRounding.ToZero` was new in .NET Core 3.0. Are you perhaps running this with an older library, one that does not recognize `MidpointRounding.ToZero`? Do you get the same results with `MidpointRounding.ToEven`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0#examples), `MidpointRounding.ToZero` does not do “midpoint rounding.” It appears Microsoft has botched the interface here:

- `MidpointRounding` was originally created as an enumeration to select between rounding to nearest with ties to even (`ToEven`) versus rounding to nearest with ties away from zero (`AwayFromZero`).
- Later additional rounding methods were added to `Math.Round`: round toward negative infinity (`ToNegativeInfinity`), round toward positive infinity (`ToPositiveInfinity`) and toward zero (`ToZero`). Note these do not round to nearest with ties toward one of those directions; they round toward one of those directions. For example, with `ToZero`, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.8 are all rounded to 3.
- Instead of creating a new enumeration with a new name such as `RoundingMethod`, Microsoft added these new values as members in `MidpointRounding`.

The result is that all five rounding methods have names in the form `MidpointRounding.Name` even though only two of them are round-to-nearest methods for which the midpoint is relevant.

(We also see terminology insensitivity in using `To` rather than `Toward`. 3.4 is rounded to 3, which is toward zero. It is not rounded to zero. IEEE 754 uses “toward” for these rounding methods.)

Adding to this the fact that [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#rounding-and-precision) tells us `Math.Round` operates by multiplying by 10<sup>*n*</sup> and rounding to an integer instead of making a correct determination of rounding for the original number, we can see what happens:

- 72.6 is converted to `double`, producing the nearest representable value, 72.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375. This is multiplied by 100, producing 7259.9999999999990905052982270717620849609375. That is rounded to an integer in the direction toward zero, producing 7259. That is divided by 100, producing 72.590000000000003410605131648480892181396484375, which prints as 72.59 if fewer than 17 digits are used.
- 82.6 is converted to `double`, producing 82.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375. That is multiplied by 100, producing 8260. The difference between this and the prior case is due to the happenstance of where the real numbers lie relative to the representable numbers. Then 8260 is divided by 100, producing 82.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375, which prints as 82.60 if fewer than 16 digits are used.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** floating points types `Single`, `Double` have loss of precision when performing mathematical operations; `Round` multiplies by 10^digit when rounding which can introduce loss of precision; `MidpointRounding.ToZero` does not round and only truncates values. So when rounding to 2 decimal places the `Round` method will calc `72.6d*100=7259.9999999999991;` (due to Double loss of precision when multiplying) which then gets truncated to `7259` because you're using `MidpointRounding.ToZero` which then is divided back by 100 to return `72.59`.

**Details:**
It has to with the precision of floating point numbers and the binary representation during the rounding being different than the literal value provided. As you discovered already, you can use decimal instead which doesn't have the same rounding issues.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#rounding-and-precision

Here's the why section from the docs:

> In order to determine whether a rounding operation involves a midpoint
> value, the Round method multiplies the original value to be rounded by
> 10<sup>n</sup>, where n is the desired number of fractional digits in the return
> value, and then determines whether the remaining fractional portion of
> the value is greater than or equal to .5. This is a slight variation
> on a test for equality, and as discussed in the "Testing for Equality"
> section of the Double reference topic, tests for equality with
> floating-point values are problematic because of the floating-point
> format's issues with binary representation and precision. This means
> that any fractional portion of a number that is slightly less than .5
> (because of a loss of precision) will not be rounded upward.

And here's what can cause it:

> Problems of precision in rounding midpoint values are most likely to
> arise in the following conditions:
>
> When a fractional value cannot be expressed precisely in the
> floating-point type's binary format.
>
> When the value to be rounded is calculated from one or more
> floating-point operations.
>
> When the value to be rounded is a Single rather than a Double or
> Decimal. For more information, see the next section, Rounding and
> single-precision floating-point values.

EDIT: Here's the example of runtime values for 72.59.  It gets multiplied by 100 during the rounding process and then truncated with .ToZero is used.  Since 72.59 * 100 has floating point rounding precision issues, it ends up as 7259.9999999999991, which then gets truncated to 7259 and divided by 100 again at the end to get 72.59.

I checked the source code for Math.Round.  Here are the relevant pieces for Double MidpointRounding.ToZero rounding, with values in comments.

```
value = 72.6; //value passed in
double num = roundPower10Double[digits]; //10^2 = 100
value *= num; //72.6d*100=7259.9999999999991
case MidpointRounding.ToZero:
    value = Truncate(value); //7259
value /= num; //7259 / 100 = 72.59;
```

Now the same for 82.6.  When * 100, it does not have the same precision issues.

```
value = 82.6; //value passed in
double num = roundPower10Double[digits]; //10^2 = 100
value *= num; //82.6d*100=8260
case MidpointRounding.ToZero:
    value = Truncate(value); //8260
value /= num; //8260 / 100 = 82.6;
```

Example code to show this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double xl = 72.6d;
    double yl = 82.6d;

    Console.WriteLine("Values * 100d:");
    Console.WriteLine(xl * 100d);
    Console.WriteLine(yl * 100d);

    Console.WriteLine("Math.Round:");
    double x = Math.Round(xl, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
    double y = Math.Round(yl, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```

Debug output:

[image: debug output]

Also check the "Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding) / Note to Callers" section in the link I provided, which provides a similar case where 2.135 has an issue but 3.135 does not:

> Notes to Callers Because of the loss of precision that can result from
> representing decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing
> arithmetic operations on floating-point values, in some cases the
> Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding) method may not appear to round
> midpoint values as specified by the mode parameter. This is
> illustrated in the following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13
> instead of 2.14. ***This occurs because internally the method multiplies
> value by 10<sup>digits</sup>, and the multiplication operation in this case
> suffers from a loss of precision.***

EDIT 2:
Also, the MidpointRounding.ToZero will always Truncate the results regardless of the midpoint. See the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0#examples

```
result = Math.Round(3.47m, 1, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
//result = 3.4
```

This means when we get 72.6 * 100 = 7259.9999999999991 as discussed earlier due to loss of precision during arithmetic operations, then because you are using MidpointRounding.ToZero then the fractional .9 is not rounded up to 7260, but instead is truncated and left as 7259, which then returns 72.59 instead of 72.6.

Comment: Are there any midpoints involved in the original question's examples (72.59 and 82.59) ?

Comment: @batetech Please take a look at my link in the question. When you enter 82.6 and 72.6 into that website it shows you the floating point representation based on the IEEE-754 standard (as implemented in C#). As you can see the fractional part for both is identical. So why don't they give the same result?

Comment: See my updated answer.  It has examples of why.

Comment: @pmcilreavy calculations on floating point numbers are not always accurate, by design. The issue is this case is that Math.Round multiplies by 10^digits and then rounds to the nearest whole number, and arithmetic operations on floating point numbers are not precise, so 72.6d * 100d returns 7259.9999999999991 instead of 7260, which then gets truncated in your case of .ToZero rounding to 7259 and then divided by 100 to return 72.59. The way the binary data is stored for doubles, as sign*1.mantissa^(exponent-1023), causes loss of precision during ops but with the benefit of less bytes used.

Comment: @JonSkeet says it well here: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/FloatingPoint "Binary floating point arithmetic is fine so long as you know what's going on and don't expect values to be exactly the decimal ones you put in your program, and don't expect calculations involving binary floating point numbers to necessarily yield precise results. Even if two numbers are both exactly represented in the type you're using, the result of an operation involving those two numbers won't necessarily be exactly represented."

Comment: This answer is inadequate to explain the problem. When 72.6 and 82.6 are converted to `Double`, the results are exactly 72.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375 and 82.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375. The linked documentation says the `Round` method multiplies by 10^n, in this case 100. Doing that multiplication with IEEE-754 “double precision” arithmetic yields 7259.9999999999990905052982270717620849609375 and 8260. The documentation says `Round` “then determines whether the remaining fractional portion of the value is greater than or equal to .5.”…

Comment: … For 72.6, the fraction portion of 7259.9999999999990905052982270717620849609375 is clearly greater than .5, so it should be rounded up to 7260, For 82.6, the fraction portion of 8260 of is clearly less than .5, so it should be rounded down to 8260. There is no evident floating-point error producing any problem around the midpoint, .5. So there is some other problem, perhaps some other arithmetic being performed that is not described in the documentation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil very good point. I'm not at my PC right now, but the source code for .NET 6.0 via VS2022 SDK I looked at earlier showed that for .ToZero it just called truncate without even checking if it was a midpoint. I think it was bc it checked earlier and saw the 2nd 0 in 72.600 was below the midpoint, so truncate should occur but then the multiplication x100 skewed the results. I'll check again tomorrow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil midpoints apparently don't matter for MidpointRounding.ToZero.  Check out this example, which shows Math.Round(3.47m, 1, MidpointRounding.ToZero); = 3.4 instead of 3.5.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0#examples  I will update the answer to include this.

Comment: How can midpoints not matter for MidpointRounding? @BateTech I suspect you are on the right track (what else could it be but the general lack of precision associated with floating point arithmetic ... except an outright bug) ... but there is a lot of confusing (and probably irrelevant) information in this answer.

Comment: According to the MidpointRounding Enum docs and the Math.Round source code, it looks like it is by (questionable) design to work this way for ToZero. ToZero was added in .NET Core 3.0, and the example in the docs for that version through .NET 8 uses a non-midpoint 3.47 and shows it rounds down to 3.4 when rounding to 1 dp.  I agree it is confusing how it is working, especially when compared to AwayFromZero. The OP says in a comment that truncate without rounding is what was expected also. But in this case the loss of precision for Double * 100 op is what causes the unexpected result.

Comment: Here's the .NET Core source code for `Math.Round`, which shows that it Truncates instead of rounding for `ToZero`. https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Math.cs,1333